How to use a Custom Validation Annotation for custom Error Handling in Spring Boot
I have a custom validation annotation that verifies a fiscal code.
FiscalCode.java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Constraint(validatedBy = FiscalCodeValidator.class)
public @interface FiscalCode {
    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

This annotation performs multiple checks, and the isValid method returns different error messages depending on how far it has validated the string.
FiscalCodeValidator.java
public class FiscalCodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FiscalCode, String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String fc, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String validationMessage = checkFC(fc);

        if (!validationMessage.isEmpty()) {
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(validationMessage).addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private String checkFC(String fc) {
        if (...) return "err1";
        ... some logic ...
        if (...) return "err2";
        ... some logic ...
        if (...) return "err3";
        ... some logic ...
        if (...) return "errN";
        ... some logic ...
        return "";
    }
}

I would like to use it both as a parameter in GET requests at the Controller level and as a field in a request object (POST, PUT).
TestController.java
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("test-get")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testGet(@FiscalCode String fc) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(fc);
    }

    @PostMapping("test-post")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testPost(@Valid @RequestBody Example example) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(example.getFiscalCode());
    }

    @PutMapping("test-put")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testPut(@Valid @RequestBody Example example) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(example.getFiscalCode());
    }

    @DeleteMapping("test-delete")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testDelete(@FiscalCode String fc) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(fc);
    }
}

Example.java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Example {
    @FiscalCode
    private String fiscalCode;
}

I would like to expose a dynamic validation error to the client (based on what the validation method returns) always in the ProblemDetail shape, with the detail property containing the error text.
GlobalExceptionHandler.java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(HandlerMethodValidationException.class)
    ResponseEntity<ProblemDetail> handleHandlerMethodValidationException(HandlerMethodValidationException ex) {
        ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatusAndDetail(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "");
        ... some logic ...
        return new ResponseEntity<>(problemDetail, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    ResponseEntity<ProblemDetail> handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatusAndDetail(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "");
        ... some logic ...
        return new ResponseEntity<>(problemDetail, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}

Is it absolutely necessary to handle each specific exception, extract the information, and insert it into a ProblemDetail? Are there more decoupled methods to achieve this? Is it possible to integrate with constraint management and provide a custom provider? Is there a best practice or recommended approach?
Thanks in advance

for what it's worth, that's what I do, but I'd be happy to be learned something if there is a better way. The key insight is the ... some logic ... can vary greatly between the type of exception, and unraveling exceptions into a presentable problem is sometimes daunting, particularly validation exceptions.

please ask one question per question it gets too broad and hard to answer otherwise. Best approach questions are generally inviting opinions which is not the point of this website... I think your approach is valid as long as it works, once you identify a drawback ask a new question about that specific issue

@JAsgarov Sorry, I wanted to ask the opinion of a Spring Boot expert because it's not a yes/no question but concerns software engineering and the entire data flow. This is the solution that came to mind, but I'm probably not making the most of the Bean Validation and Hibernate Validator APIs. Thanks anyway for the advice.

@Eric I thought about wrapping everything inside my own exception and making the Validator throw my custom exception instead of using strings. The problem is that if I throw exceptions inside the Validator, it then disrupts the internal framework's functioning and gives me warnings. So, I left the default flow with the boolean of the isValid method.

The most difficult issue to address is that everything is integrated into the framework, so it doesn't seem possible to isolate only the errors from @FiscalCode. The framework proceeds with validation and throws its internal exceptions, distinguishing between validation exceptions for methods and those for arguments. It's not possible to isolate and read only the validation errors; you have to intercept those of the context (methods, arguments, types, etc.).
